# How to select first value - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the first date for each invoice as you can see below:

This is my data:

```
EC_Refpiece | EC_Date
FA0001      | 01/01/2019
FA0001      | 25/08/2018
FA0002      | 12/01/2019
FA0002      | 15/04/2017
```

And this is the result I want :

```
EC_Refpiece | EC_Date
FA0001      | 25/08/2018
FA0002      | 15/04/2017
```

Comment: Please show us your code and indicate what you don't understand.

Comment: If all you want is the first date, use a simple `GROUP BY` and `MIN`. Are you looking for something different perhaps?

Comment: @Rahul I googled it first but I didn't get the result I'm looking for! Anyway if you can't help at least don't be negative. Thank you. :)

Comment: Okay so, this is what i wrote in google `select first date from a bunch of records sql server` and this is the FIRST link i got: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736820/sql-how-to-select-earliest-row. Not being negative but you are required to try to work on the solution yourself and then post a question.

Comment: @Rahul Okay sir ,my bad! Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
SELECT EC_Refpiece, MIN(EC_date)
FROM table
GROUP BY EC_Refpiece
```

Comment: Thank you so much, MIN function works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the first, ie minimum date, all you need to do is a simple GROUP BY:

```
select EC_Refpiece, MIN(EC_DATE)
from ThatTable
group by EC_Refpiece
```

If you want to retrieve the first *row* though, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this :

```
   with invoices as 
   (
       select 
           EC_Refpiece,
           EC_Date,
           ....           
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by EC_Refpiece order by EC_Date) RN
       from ThatTable
   )
   select * from invoices
   where RN=1
```

ROW_NUMBER partitions the results according to the `PARTITION BY` clause and calculates a sequential row number for each partition, after sorting all results according to the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Thank you so much, MIN function works well.